# Java Array display array values over an amount of characters

Tags: java, arrays, count, character

I am stuck. I have my array with data the user inputs. After their information is entered the program asks if they want to see items with characters above 10 or below. I can't seem to figure out this section. Below is where I am currently with the code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CategorizeStrings {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] array = new String[20];
    System.out.println("Please enter anything..., or press QUIT to quit.");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = s.nextLine();
        boolean result = Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch("QUIT"::equals);
       if(result) 
       {
           break;
       }
    }
    String str = null;
    int len = -1;
    
    System.out.println("Would you like to display strings with above 10 charaters (Above) or below 10 characters (Below)? Type Above or Below:");
    String answer = s.nextLine();
    if(answer == "Above"){
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] != null)
                len ++;
            if(array[i].charAt(i)>10)
                for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
                    if(array[x] == str )
                    System.out.print(len);
                    System.out.print(array[x] + " ");
            }
        }

    }
        else
        {
            
        }
    

    System.out.println();
}
```

}

The block of code I'm struggling with is:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] != null)
                len ++;
            if(array[i].charAt(i)>10)
                for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
                    if(array[x] == str )
                    System.out.print(len);
                    System.out.print(array[x] + " ");
            }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `charAt` method?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm open to any method to gather the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print the words that have above 10 characters

```
       for (String value : array) {
            if (value != null) {
                if (value.length() > 10) {
                    System.out.print(value + " ");
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I would do it

Also note that Strings can't be compared using '=='
You should use equal or contentEquals

For example:

```
if (string1.equals(string2)) {
    // Insert code here
}
```

or

```
if (string1.contentEquals(string2)) {
    // Insert code here
}
```

Comment: That was it. I was completely overthinking it. Thank you!